# div scroll with jquery animate not smooth

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I have put up my sample working code in http://jsfiddle.net/ULeuu/1/ . The problem is i am trying to animate using jquery but the scrolling is not smooth. Is there a way so that i can make div scroll smoothly

Comment: can you elaborate? Which browser you are using? What version of jquery?

Comment: I think he means that if the mouse is held down on next, it should continuously scroll and not scroll and stop, scroll and stop, etc.

Comment: @ShantanuD I want the way what Purmou has pointed out

Comment: @Purmou Yes Purmou you got my point right. Is there a better way to get rid of the issue i am facing. I want to make the speed duration flexible but the scroll and stop problem on next mouse down in my demo code is what became a major problem to proceed further

Answer (score 4):

- First of all, synchronize your `setTimeout`'s and `.animate()`'s duration by setting animation duration to `400`, like the timeout.
- Second, use `linear` easing to remove any stacks in animation:

  ```
  $("#slide").stop().animate({"left":leftVal + 177  + 'px'}, { "duration": 400, "easing": "linear" });
  ```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ULeuu/4/).

Comment: I have seen the correction you did but there is some sort of visual distortion during scroll. I have already tried this but not getting the effect of how scroll plugins works. Can it be made smooth along with visual clearity otherwise in touch devices the slight visual difference is even more clearly noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Insted of `fast` give some value in `.animate` like

```
 $("#slide").stop().animate({"left":leftVal + 177  + 'px'},1000);
```

Comment: That just makes it slower. If you notice, the animation has a very brief pause midway through. That's what he wants to get rid of.

Comment: @Ajinkya I have tried this but not able to get rid of what Purmou has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal to have continuous scroll on hover?
Use a setInterval with the same amount of time as your animation, with linear easing.
- using jQuery 1.9.1

```
(function(){
                var myObject = {
                    leftInt: '',
                    rightInt: '',
                    init: function(){
                        $this = this;
                        $(function(){
                            $this.eventListeners();
                        });
                    },
                    eventListeners: function(){
                        $('#prev').on("mouseenter", myObject.goLeft);
                        $('#prev').on("mouseleave", myObject.stopLeft);
                        $('#next').on("mouseenter", myObject.goRight);
                        $('#next').on("mouseleave", myObject.stopRight);
                    },
                    goLeft: function(){
                        myObject.leftInt = setInterval(myObject.slideLeft, 300);
                    },
                    goRight: function(){
                        myObject.rightInt = setInterval(myObject.slideRight, 300);
                    },
                    stopLeft: function(){
                        clearInterval(myObject.leftInt);
                    },
                    stopRight: function(){
                        clearInterval(myObject.rightInt);
                    },
                    slideLeft: function(){
                        $("#slide").stop(true, true).animate({"left":'+=20px'}, 300, 'linear');
                    },
                    slideRight: function(){
                        $("#slide").stop(true, true).animate({"left":'-=20px'}, 300, 'linear');
                    }
                }
                myObject.init();
            })();
```